# Как изменить значение атрибута value в теге input?

Tags: поиск, теги, javascript, атрибуты

Необходимо менять значение именно используя `Javascript`, т.к. поисковая форма генерится сама по себе и доступа к коду нету.

Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 8):

pure_js:

```
document.getElementById('someInputId').value = 'changed Value';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#someInputId').val('changed Value');
```

Comment: Это должно вызываться по какому-то событию, или просто в конец страницы запихнуть?

Comment: как вам будет угодно...можете так :
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($('#someInputId').val('changed Value'));
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").val("Значение");
});
Или
<input onclick/onblur="this.value='Значения'">
```

Смотря какая у вас ситуация. 
Не забываем подключить [библиотечку Jquery](http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js).

Comment: Да и document.getElementById('someInputId').value = 'changed Value'; то же как knes написал ниже)

Comment: Пробую пихать в конец страницы - не работает...

Comment: Дайте ссылку.